# Sumar campos de un Inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Que tal quisiera saber como puedo sumar dos campos que pertenezcan a un inner join
tengo este codigo pero no me realiza la suma completa solo recupera todos los valores de las columnas y los suma de 1 en 1, en vez de solo hacer la suma completa de toda la columna por ejemplo:
NumeroPlantas  = 163,237  y
NumeroJornales = 61

```
     SELECT SUM(ACT.NumeroDePlantas) as NumeroPlantas , 
            SUM(ACT.NumDeJornales) as NumeroJornales   
 
     FROM AGRMastPlanRendimiento MPR (NOLOCK)

     INNER JOIN vwGENPredios ACT (NOLOCK) ON (ACT.intGENPredioKey = MPR.intGENPredioLink)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esa consulta recibo estos valores de la imagen y lo que yo espero es la suma de ellos
por ejemplo en NumeroPlantas el resultado de la suma seria 163,237 y de NumeroJornales seria 61

Comment: es posible que tienes muy pocos resultados por que tu _join_ está mal. Deberia ser algo asi `select ... from TablaA inner join TablaB on TablaA.id = TablaB.id`

Comment: Disculpas ahí van las key de los campos con los que se van a vincular `TablaA.id = TablaB.KeyTablaA`

Comment: Puedes agregar los valores de como tienes el resultado a tu pregunta(así llega a más gente) y que esperas del resultado por favor.

Comment: Listo lo añadi abajo espero sea mas claro

Comment: Bueno te explico lo próximo que puedes realizar, realiza un _sum_ nuevamente sobre tus resultados. Para explicarte mejor ahí los tienes separados por que se sumaron sobre el _join_ que realizaste. Es decir sería lo siguiente: `select sum(NumeroPlantas), sum(NumeroJornales) from (--aca va la query que ya tienes)`